# iterate though column names of a dataframe to create new dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Imagine that we have a df(100,5). All columns are named. Let s say for example we have the following

```
df1:

A       B       C       D      E
1       2       3       4      5
.       .       .       .      .
.       .       .       .      .
```

I want to loop through the column names and create a new dataframe while calling another function that does some calculations with the values in the cells. I have something like this

```
new_df = []
for name in df:
    result = my_function(vector1, df[name])
    new_df[name] = function2(result)
```

If I have it like this, I get the following error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I have also tried like this

```
new_df = []
for name in df:
    result = my_function(vector1, df[name])
    new_df[[name]] = function2(result)
```

EDIT : When I was writing the post I  accidentally wrote

```
for name in new_df:
```

What I meant to write was

```
for name in df:
```

Comment: you are looping through an empty list `new_df`. If you actually want to loop try something like `for name in df.columns:`

Comment: Hey, I accidentally wrote it like that when I was creating the post.  I fixed it now. In my code I loop through the column names of my df(1000,5)

Answer (score 2):

Think this is what you want. You were looping through an empty list.
Also, a `new_df` as a list can't be indexed as `new_df[name] =`. You'd either need to use a dictionary or just append.

```
new_df = []
for name in df.columns:
    result = my_function(vector1, df[name])
    new_df.append(function2(result))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df, columns = df.columns)
```